# Expanding date in a BASH script set up with configuration file

Tags: bash

I have taken over a script that sends out some files from our database to customers. It has a `.cfg` file containing configuration variables and a `.cmd` file that performs the actual script.

For e.g. in the `.cfg` file the e-mail body is set, i.e.:

```
# --- EMAIL BODY BEGIN ---
# Please see attached report.
#
# Report generated on `date +"%A %d %B %Y"`
# --- EMAIL BODY END ---
```

The section in the `.cmd` that pulls this information is:

```
  if [ "$4" != "" ]
  then
    mail_body_begin=`cat $CFGFILE | grep -n "^# --- $4: EMAIL BODY BEGIN ---" |head -1 | cut -d: -f1`
    mail_body_end=`cat $CFGFILE | grep -n "^# --- $4: EMAIL BODY END ---" | hea -1 | cut -d: -f1`
  fi

  if [ "$4" == "" -o "$mail_body_begin" == "" -o "$mail_body_end" == "" ]
  then
    mail_body_begin=`cat $CFGFILE | grep -n "^# --- EMAIL BODY BEGIN ---" | hea -1 | cut -d: -f1`
    mail_body_end=`cat $CFGFILE | grep -n "^# --- EMAIL BODY END ---" | head -1| cut -d: -f1`
  fi

  mail_body_end=`expr $mail_body_end - 1`
  mail_body_len=`expr $mail_body_end - $mail_body_begin`
  cat $CFGFILE | head -$mail_body_end | tail -$mail_body_len | cut -c3- >> $MAIL_IN
```

I personally added the `date +"%A %d %B %Y"` to the e-mail body but it doesn't get expanded automatically by the `.cmd` (so the user just sees the `date` command etc.). I have looked at this for a while but can't seem to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the configuration file is only ever read, but never executed.

You put a marker like #MYDATE# into the configuration file and within one of the pipelines that extract things from the configuration file add a sed curse to replace it, roughly along the lines of

```
 ... | sed -e "s/#MYDATE#/$(date +'%A %d %B %Y')/" | ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of embedding a command substitution in the file, just put a `printf` format character:

```
# --- EMAIL BODY BEGIN ---
# Please see attached report.
#
# Report generated on %s
# --- EMAIL BODY END ---
```

Then use `printf` to process the template once it is extracted. The script itself
can be greatly simplified using `awk`.

```
# The regular expressions that will match the template markers,
# taking into account $4 being set or not.
begin_marker="^# --- ${4:+$4: }EMAIL BODY BEGIN ---"
end_marker="^# --- ${4:+$4: }EMAIL BODY END ---"

body=$(awk -v b="$begin_marker" \
           -v e="$end_marker" \
         '  $0 ~ e {selected=0};
          selected {sub("# *", "", $0); print};
            $0 ~ b {selected=1}' "$CFGFILE")
printf "$body\n" "$(date +"%A %d %B %Y")" >> $MAI_IN
```

Comment: Thanks. That is much simpler (and works!) but there is a slight problem in that when I replace my section with yours every e-mail attachment is blank. When I switch the section back to the original the attachments have content. I do not see anything in that section that would effect the contents of the attachments, do you? Is there any further information that I can provide?

Comment: How does `$MAI_IN` get used to eventually send the email? One (possibly pointless) thing to try is to add a newline to the `printf` statement, to restore the newline lost by capturing `awk`'s output in `body` (I'll make that change above as well).

Comment: It's actually `$MAIL_IN` (typing error in original question has been corrected). The line I think you're looking for is `cat $MAIL_IN | mailconv $MAILFILES | tee tg.mail | $SENDMAIL $SENDER -t`.

Comment: The attachments still do not have any content even with the new line amendment. When reverting that section of the script back the attachments have content. Any other ideas?

Comment: The below answer by Harald works. I would prefer to use `printf` but at the moment can't seem to get it to work.